# In a sharepoint list what are the three horizontal dots called?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, menu

Seriously what's it's name? I'm getting conflicting information and it seems to be different for each platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are talking about the 3 dots then it is called **ellipsis.** menu.

In the below picture, you can see the 3 dots highlighted in green.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In short you can call "ellipsis"

Comment: For long, users call it "that thing next to the document name" or "the what?" or "I can't see that" or "Oh! That! What is that?"